# Does Yampa have support for memoizing signal functions?

Tags: haskell, signals, frp, arrows, yampa

I have written a basic signal function in Yampa as follows:

```hs
sf :: SF Int Int
sf = arr $ \x -> trace "1 * 2 = 2" (x * 2)
```

This function doubles its input and prints "1 * 2 = 2" to the console to indicate that it has been called. I then tested sf with the code below:

```hs
embed sf (deltaEncode 1 (repeat 1))
```

As you can see, only the value of 1 is provided as input to sf. I expected Yampa to have some form of memoization to prevent the repeated calling of sf with the same input, since the function passed to `arr` should be pure. However, it appears that such support is not available, as "1 * 2 = 2" is printed repeatedly.

To provide additional context, I have some experience with reactive programming using React, and I am currently exploring the concept of FRP. Yampa is my first FRP library of choice, and I was hoping to find something similar to React's `memo` in Yampa to handle recomputation efficiently. I searched `a -> b -> SF a b` in Hoogle and found `arrPrim`. But it didn't work as I expected either.

Is there a way to achieve this in Yampa? If not, how can Yampa execute signal functions efficiently?

Furthermore, the example I provided does not involve time-varying systems, as it simply ignores time. I had initially thought that Yampa could be useful for discrete events-only systems also if it provided something like `memo` at least. However, if such a thing doesn't exist, then I believe Yampa may only be useful for time-varying systems. Is this understanding accurate?

As I am still in the early stages of learning about FRP, I am concerned that I may have misunderstood some concepts. I would greatly appreciate it if you could clarify any misunderstandings or recommend other FRP libraries that better meet my expectations.

Comment: The first suggestion that comes to mind would be using a library [such as *MemoTrie*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.10/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html#v:memo) to memoise your pure functions as appropriate. There should be no issues in using that along with Yampa.

Comment: Doesn't MemoTrie memoize every value passed to the function? I've expected signal functions to memorize only the previous value. It would be more useful than MemoTrie when the space of the input is large, but the inputs passed to the signal function rarely changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Haskell, there is no default for memoizing functions. The way Haskell's laziness works is that values are default immutable, so won't be recomputed unless you use a different variable. In this case, the *function* is memoized, but its *results* are not. This is because under the hood, you are calling this function on a list of inputs:

```
$ ghci
Prelude> let xs = take 5 $ repeat 1
Prelude> import Debug.Trace
Prelude Debug.Trace> let f x = trace "hi" $ x * 2
Prelude Debug.Trace> f <$> xs
[hi
2,hi
2,hi
2,hi
2,hi
2]
```

Since each input is distinct, there is no memoization. However, you can memoize your own functions pretty straight forwardly. Simply use a stateful signal function that keeps track of the last input, using [`sscanPrim`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Yampa-0.14.2/docs/FRP-Yampa.html#v:sscanPrim):

```
-- test.hs
import FRP.Yampa
import Debug.Trace

memoized :: Eq a => a -> (a -> b) -> SF a b
memoized x0 f = sscanPrim memo x0 (f x0)
  where
    memo old new | old == new = Nothing
                 | otherwise = Just (new, f new)

sf :: SF Int Int
sf = memoized 1 $ \x -> trace "1 * 2 = 2" (x * 2)
--

$ ghci test.hs
*Main> take 10 $ embed sf (deltaEncode 1 (repeat 1))
[1 * 2 = 2
2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a follow-up question - is `memoized` (or something similar) commonly used in Yampa applications? Based on my prior experience with reactive programming in other languages, `memoized` is a crucial feature that is provided by the library. However, I have noticed that it is not included in the Yampa library, which leads me to wonder if I have misunderstood certain concepts in Yampa.

Comment: I can only speak for [Netwire](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire), but IME this is not a common pattern used in Haskell's arrowized FRP frameworks. I'm speculating, but the reason for this is likely that these libraries are built as generalized systems (e.g. can be used to model a distributed network, or a physics simulation), and not specific to something that would benefit from that kind of memoization (not to mention that requires handling state). Anything as expensive as e.g. a layout recomputation as a result of a reactive system is likely application specific.